# TransactSQL: How to search table for ntext field starting with '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server

My ASP web page makes a SQL Server database call to try and find all rows that have a column that begins with the character '-'. (english is an ntext column)

I can execute the following query no problem in Enterprise Manager and get the desired results:

```
SELECT english FROM Translations WHERE english LIKE N'-%' ORDER BY english
```

But when I execute this query in my web page, I get a NOT FOUND (Recordset EOF).
Any normal alpha char A-Z works fine, but the '-' fails, even though there are records with the content beginning with that character.

I believe the '-' must be some sort of special char, but how do I tweak the query so that it returns the results it should?

Thanks
Experts!

Comment: You mean to say you want fetch the data starting from '-' from english column of Translation table ? Is that you want to say ?

Comment: WHY are you still using ntext at this late date? Enterprise Manager? Are you using sql server 2000? But it seems the problem is in your application code - so how does that query get generated and then executed in your app?

Comment: To be clear, I wish to fetch all rows where the first character in the column named 'english' is the '-' character.

Comment: I am working with a legacy system.

Comment: You can achieve it by this : SELECT english FROM Translations WHERE english LIKE N'[-]%' ORDER BY english

Comment: This works fine when any A-Z character is used, only fails when searching for rows where the column data begins with the '-' character.

set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open sql, objConn
if objRS.EOF then 
    mytrace("NOT FOUND")
end if

Comment: The use of [-] also fails. It did work in Enterprise Manager, but not in the web query.

Comment: Once again - post the application code that generates and submits the query (and tag it as well). Absent that, no one can offer help and there is a good chance your question will be closed due to lack of information. You might want to try using LEFT instead of LIKE since you only need to test the first character - but that seems like a stretch.

Comment: And a last comment - it isn't important that you are using a legacy system - and I hope that isn't just an excuse. It IS important that you identify your environment so your readers can understand your question in the proper context.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to post the full source but the stackoverflow told me I exceeded the comment character limit (was just about 20 lines)

Comment: My suspicion would be the same as [the issue here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/search-for-hyphen-in-database-it-does-not-find-the-hyphen) (the hyphen variant being searched for is a different variant than contained in the text.

Comment: There are different types of dashes -- the most common being em-dash and en-dash.  You are probably just searching for the wrong character.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin & Gordon! That was it!

My suspicion would be the same as the issue here (the hyphen variant being searched for is a different variant than contained in the text. – Martin Smith yesterday

There are different types of dashes -- the most common being em-dash and en-dash. You are probably just searching for the wrong character. – Gordon Linoff yesterday